# Alter the values in a column

Tags: postgresql

I have at hand the following table (for data migration):

```
recvtimets     |         recvtime         | fiwareservicepath | entityid |   entitytype    |     attrname     |    attrtype     |               attrvalue               | attrmd
---------------+--------------------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+--------
 1559573267088 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.88Z  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | location         | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.613502,41.143994]} | []
 1559573267088 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.88Z  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | relativeHumidity | Number          | 59.1                                  | []
 1559573267088 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.88Z  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | dateObserved     | Text            | 2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00             | []
 1559573267088 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.88Z  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | illuminance      | None            | null                                  | []
 1559573267088 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.88Z  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | temperature      | Number          | 24.9                                  | []
 1559573267088 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.88Z  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | name             | Text            | Rua das Flores                        | []
 1559573267782 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.782Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | name             | Text            | Praca do Marques - pole 1             | []
 1559573267782 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.782Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | illuminance      | None            | null                                  | []
 1559573267782 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.782Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | temperature      | Number          | 21.9                                  | []
 1559573267782 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.782Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | dateObserved     | Text            | 2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00             | []
 1559573267782 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.782Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | location         | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.603802,41.161671]} | []
 1559573267782 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.782Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | relativeHumidity | Number          | 80.8                                  | []
 1559573267696 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.696Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | name             | Text            | Fundacao de Serralves                 | []
 1559573267696 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.696Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | illuminance      | None            | null                                  | []
 1559573267696 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.696Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | location         | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.65915,41.1591]}    | []
 1559573267696 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.696Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | relativeHumidity | Number          | 1                                     | []
 1559573267696 | 2019-06-03T14:47:47.696Z | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | dateObserved     | Text            | 2015-09-01T10:16:22+01:00             | []
```

The first two columns depict the timestamp the application writes to the database (reading from some db). The time for which data was actually recorded however, is the `dateObserved` attribute in the `attrname` column and its corresponding value is that shown in `attrvalue` column.

This means the first 6 rows (having `2019-06-03T14:47:47.88Z` in the `recvtime` column were recorded on `2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00` (shown on  `attrvalue` column), i.e. `dateObserved = 2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00`

The next 6 rows having `2019-06-03T14:47:47.782Z` in the `recvtime` column were recorded on `2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00`, i.e. `dateObserved =2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00`

Likewise, the last 6 rows having `recvtime` as `2019-06-03T14:47:47.696Z` were recorded on `2015-09-01T10:16:22+01:00` i.e. `dateObserved = 2015-09-01T10:16:22+01:00`

The goal is to alter the contents of `recvtime` column such that these values are replaced by the date recorded as contain in the `attrvalue` for the respective rows.

Accordingly, the end result becomes as in following table(i.e. the final table to produce this):

```
recvtimets     |           recvtime         | fiwareservicepath | entityid |   entitytype    |     attrname     |    attrtype     |               attrvalue               | attrmd
---------------+----------------------------+-------------------+----------+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------+--------
 1559573267088 | 2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | location         | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.613502,41.143994]} | []
 1559573267088 | 2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | relativeHumidity | Number          | 59.1                                  | []
 1559573267088 | 2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | dateObserved     | Text            | 2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00             | []
 1559573267088 | 2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | illuminance      | None            | null                                  | []
 1559573267088 | 2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | temperature      | Number          | 24.9                                  | []
 1559573267088 | 2015-09-01T10:15:57+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | name             | Text            | Rua das Flores                        | []
 1559573267782 | 2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | name             | Text            | Praca do Marques - pole 1             | []
 1559573267782 | 2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | illuminance      | None            | null                                  | []
 1559573267782 | 2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | temperature      | Number          | 21.9                                  | []
 1559573267782 | 2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | dateObserved     | Text            | 2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00             | []
 1559573267782 | 2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | location         | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.603802,41.161671]} | []
 1559573267782 | 2015-09-01T10:16:24+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | relativeHumidity | Number          | 80.8                                  | []
 1559573267696 | 2015-09-01T10:16:22+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | name             | Text            | Fundacao de Serralves                 | []
 1559573267696 | 2015-09-01T10:16:22+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | illuminance      | None            | null                                  | []
 1559573267696 | 2015-09-01T10:16:22+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | location         | StructuredValue | {"coordinates":[-8.65915,41.1591]}    | []
 1559573267696 | 2015-09-01T10:16:22+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | relativeHumidity | Number          | 1                                     | []
 1559573267696 | 2015-09-01T10:16:22+01:00  | /basic            | 001      | WeatherObserved | dateObserved     | Text            | 2015-09-01T10:16:22+01:00             | []
```

How do I achieve this in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.recvtimets, 
       t2.attrvalue recvtime,
       t1.fiwareservicepath,
       t1.entityid,
       t1.entitytype,
       t1.attrname,
       t1.attrtype,
       t1.attrvalue,
       t1.attrmd
FROM tablename t1
JOIN tablename t2 ON t1.recvtimets = t2.recvtimets
                 AND t2.attrname = 'dateObserved'
WHERE t1.attrname != 'dateObserved'
```